# XPath lower-case() to get a collection of lowercased values

Tags: java, xpath, xpath-2.0

Given the XML instance:

```
<fruits>
    <fruit>Apple</fruit>
    <fruit>Orange</fruit>
    <fruit>Banana</fruit>
</fruits>
```

I am using the loop:

```
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/fruits/fruit/text()");
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i = 0 ; i < nodes.getLength() ; i++) 
    System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
```

to print a list of fruit names. Is there any way to use `lower-case` in the outer XPath expression so that the names are *already lowercased* in the returned sequence? I don't want to use the `String` `toLowerCase()` Java method or invoke the `lower-case()` function on each item as in:

```
System.out.println(xpath.compile("lower-case(.)").evaluate(nodes.item(i)));
```

... is there a way to accomplish that in one XPath expression, that's evaluated only once for the outer loop?

I have the following Saxon dependency in my **Ivy** file so I also have access to XPath 2.0 features:

```
<dependency org="net.sf.saxon" name="Saxon-HE" rev="9.4"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Java Only Supports XPath 1.0

Plain Java's XPath evaluator does not support XPath 2.0, so you cannot use `fn:lower-case(...)` at all. Use Java's `toLowerCase()` function for each single result.

#### If you've got XPath 2.0

If you're using some other XPath engine, you would use this expression to convert every fruit name to lower case and still receive single fruit names:

```
/fruits/fruit/text()/lower-case(.)
```

#### Simulating `fn:lower-case(...)` in XPath 1.0

All you could do is use `translate(some-string, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')`, but this only works on single values.

Comment: I am using Saxon 9.4 HE so I have XPath 2.0 (I updated the post), `/fruits/fruit/text()/lower-case()` complains with ` Function lower-case() must have 1 argument` (this is coming out of Saxon's guts).

Comment: Aye, you've got to include the current context. Didn't put enough attention to the answer, now everything should be fine.

Comment: Now the code blows on the line where the call to `evaluate` is, with: `Cannot convert XPath value to Java object: required class is org.w3c.dom.NodeList; supplied value has type xs:string`

Comment: Haven't got Saxon on my machine so I cannot reproduce the problem right now, but I guess you have to change the second parameter to [`STRING`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPathConstants.html#STRING). `lower-case()` does return `xs:string`s [which are not of data type node](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-datamodel/#types-hierarchy).